# Different User Account for Database Mirror testing

Tags: sql-server, database, mirror

for Sql server Database Mirror testing(Witness mode), we can have such connection string.

`sqlConnectionString="data source=[PRINCIPALSERVER];
   failover partner=[MIRRORSERVER];initial catalog=ASPState;user id=[DBUSER];
   password=[DBPWD];network=dbmssocn;"`

However, I encouter one issue that we use different User id and password for Principal server and Mirror server.

Is it able to connect to two database servers with different user/password?
Does any one know how to configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the connection string only has support for configuring a failover partner. It uses the same user credentials when connecting to both partners

Comment: Thanks for your response. It makes sense to use same user credential for one connection string. Do you think is there any way to make it work in this case? Or we have to change the user credentail to same one? Any way on code level?

Comment: Best option is to use the same user credentials for both partners. if you want check and handle on code level (which i do NOT recommend ) you could query to check which instance is the PRINCIPAL and then connect to it
SELECT * FROM sys.database_mirroring
WHERE database_id = db_id('<database>')

Comment: We do not have sql sentences in our C# client. Will try to change the password. Thanks anyway.